# How to generate a tree grid using jqgrid?

Tags: c#, jquery, jqgrid

I want to generate a tree node table using jqgrid.
For example the html table is like this.

```
Id Name ParentId UserId
1   xx     null    1
2   yy     null    1
3   yy     null    2
```

There are two questions that I have not solved.

**Question one is as follows:**

I need to pass two parameter from the parent Row data to server for query child data. For example when I click the parentRow I need to pass the 'Id' and 'UserId' to server for querying child data.

For this I have no idea to get the UserId ,I can only get the 'Id' on each click

```
  $('#mytable').jqGrid({
                url: 'home/getdata',
                ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',
                treeGrid: true,
                treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
                ExpandColumn: 'Name',
                 postData: postData,
                colNames: ['ID', 'Name',  'ParentID','UserId'],
                colModel: [
                { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', hidden: true, width: 1, key: true },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 200, fixed: true },
                { name: 'ParentID', index: 'ParentID', hidden: true, width: 1 },
                { name: 'UserId', index: 'UserId', width: 100 },
                ],
                autowidth: true,
                height: 'auto'
            });
```

on the server side(C#) I can user `Request["nodeid"]` and `Request["n_level"]`  to get 'Id' and level.  But I want to get 'UserId' at the same time, so how could I do this?

**Question two:**

I want to query differnt datasource according the condition the front choose. For example I put a datetime picker in my page,
and I want mytable(jqgrid) to reload after I change the datetime picker.
The question is that, I don't know how to pass the time value to server when I click the parent row each time and when I use `$("mytable").triggle("reloadGrid")`, it seems to not work. The grid table has no refresh.

Comment: The test data which you included contains everywhere `null` in `ParentId`, so it's difficult to speak about TreeGrid with the data. Moreover the values in `Id` (you mean probably `ID`) column are **the same** as in `UserId` column. It would be helpful if you would include the data which more close to *really*. The problems with filling of the data is frequently the origin of problems. What data contains `UserId`? Do you really need no have hidden `'ID'` column?

Comment: You should post "Question two:" as separate question. It's important that you include JavaScript code and HTML fragments which shows exactly what you do. If you write about some problems with `reloadGrid` then it's really important to know which `datatype` you use and whether you use `loadonce: true` or not. You wrote about "the parent row". So you use probably TreeGrid or Subgrid. You write about some Datepicker. Is it inside of the grid, in the searching toolbar or outside of the grid? How you define `postData`? The current text of the "Question two" can be interpreted in many different ways

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:treegrid

I believe this should be sufficient enough information if you haven't already checked this out.